# How to print Log File CodeIgniter in browser?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have Log File like this in folders logs/log.php

```
ERROR - 2018-09-17 06:51:03 --> Severity: Warning --> Illegal string offset 'Catatan' /var/www/html/minilos/application/views/minilos/form_akkk.php 483
ERROR - 2018-09-17 06:51:03 --> Severity: Warning --> Illegal string offset 'Catatan' /var/www/html/minilos/application/views/minilos/form_akkk.php 483
ERROR - 2018-09-17 06:51:03 --> Severity: Warning --> Illegal string offset 'Rekomendasi' /var/www/html/minilos/application/views/minilos/form_akkk.php 502
ERROR - 2018-09-17 06:51:03 --> Severity: Warning --> Illegal string offset 'Rekomendasi' /var/www/html/minilos/application/views/minilos/form_akkk.php 502
ERROR - 2018-09-17 06:51:03 --> Severity: Warning --> Illegal string offset 'name' /var/www/html/minilos/application/views/minilos/form_akkk.php 507
ERROR - 2018-09-17 06:51:03 --> Severity: Warning --> Illegal string offset 'name' /var/www/html/minilos/application/views/minilos/form_akkk.php 507
ERROR - 2018-09-17 06:51:03 --> Severity: Warning --> Illegal string offset 'name' /var/www/html/minilos/application/views/minilos/form_akkk.php 509
```

I am using CodeIgniter 2.2.6

how to print Log File ini browser?

Comment: `var_dump(file_get_contents('path/to/log.log'));` Would that not just work?

Answer (score 1):

Just grab and echo the contents.

```
$file = file_get_contents('/path/to/your/log/file');
echo $file;
```